# sql insert query with duplicate id's

Tags: sql

i have table with id column and param column

and i try to add some param only where this param not exist

for example my table is:

```
+--+-----+
|id|param|
+--+-----+
|2 |a    |
+--+-----+
|2 |b    |
+--+-----+
|3 |a    |
+--+-----+
|3 |b    |
+--+-----+
|4 |a    |
+--+-----+
|4 |b    |
+--+-----+
|4 |c    |
+--+-----+
```

now i try to add "c" *param* to all id's that don't have c *param*

how i can do it in one sql query? 
(the param that i wont to add it hard coded like "c" in the example param and i dont need to take it from any other table...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `insert . . . select`.  The `select` part just needs to find the `id`s that do not have that parameter:

```
insert into t(id, param)
    select id, 'C'
    from t
    group by id
    having sum(case when param = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `MERGE ... SELECT` inserting  when there is no match.

```
MERGE INTO mytable t
  USING ( SELECT DISTINCT id, 'C'
            FROM mytable
        ) as i (key, val)
  ON id=key and param=val
  WHEN NOT MATCHED  THEN
    INSERT (id,param) VALUES (key,val)
```